# Почему функция не имеет доступ к переменным внешней функции?

Tags: javascript

```
fetchValue = function (callBack){

    var taker = "1";
    callBack();
}


exportValue = function()  {
        alert(taker);
}

fetchValue(exportValue);  //Uncaught ReferenceError: taker is not defined
```

В чем проблема? Я думал если fetchValue не находит переменную у себя, она ищет ее в exportValue, т.к. это функция-родитель, разве нет?

Comment: Неправильно понимаете. https://learn.javascript.ru/closures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Родитель" определяется в момент **создания** функции, а не в момент вызова.

Таким образом в данном коде две независимые функции не имеющие доступа к локальным переменным друг друга.

Чтобы код заработал, `exportValue` должна быть **объявлена** внутри `fetchValue`

```
fetchValue = function (){

    var taker = "1";
    var exportValue = function()  {
        alert(taker);
    }
    exportValue();
}
fetchValue();
```